# Is there a way to solve coding challenges more easy?

Tags: algorithms

### I'm always using debugging and writing test cases to solve coding challenges. It's been very helpful so far but now that problems became very complex, its not good enough.

Is there a way to use tools like:

- state machine diagrams
- logic tables
- regular expressions
- something else

in order to create from there the pseudo code or something that **provides a cognitive structure to create from there the implemented code** in the technology of preference: C, C++, Javascript, etc.

In other words:

- A **verification process where I check my solution or part of it is going to work before typing anything in the keyboard**
- A **scaffold to the thinking process in order to arrive at the solution faster and with better quality**
- A **theoretical frame to make the solution faster by not testing so much**.
- A **model from which the pseudo code can emerge easier**.
- A **workflow that relies less in heuristics and more on some other formal method**

This is the coding challenge that made me think it could be solved in a more professional way:

1. https://imgur.com/eW1bh5r
2. https://imgur.com/cTulsGL
3. https://imgur.com/4EeTC6Z
4. https://imgur.com/ewVwb8K

Maybe this question belongs to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ and not here. I'm sorry if there is a way my question doesn't meet the standards.  If so, please let me know how to perfect it. This is my first one and I have no intent in bringing trouble to the community. I know this question might be very vague but my doubt is very vague too. Because I'm not only asking for directions, I'm also asking where to go.

Comment: "Pseudo code or something that provides a cognitive structure to create from there the implemented code", by this do you mean an _Algorithm_? If you are looking to test faster and more accurately, it's probably best to randomly generate a lot of test cases (along with some manual edge cases if they aren't likely to get generated).

Comment: Thank you ryan! Exactly. But I need a structure to generate algorithms more efficiently.
I'll check about randomly generated test cases in the future, they might help but I'm looking for something else now: maybe a set of a graphs and/or diagrams.

Comment: In terms of generating algorithms (or code), this is referred to as [program synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_synthesis). Though, I feel if you are using these for coding challenges, this is not what you should use. Could you give an example of a coding challenge you are experiencing and how you would like to make the process more stream-lined? I think this question is very broad, it may help to scope it down. You probably won't find an automated approach for coding challenges as that would mostly defeat the purpose of the challenge.

Comment: Yes! I feel you get the idea of this question. This is the coding challenge that made me post this question:
1
https://imgur.com/eW1bh5r
2
https://imgur.com/cTulsGL
3
https://imgur.com/4EeTC6Z
4
https://imgur.com/ewVwb8K

Comment: The answer to this question is that there is a very very broad area of research revolving around it (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_programming)) and you are unlikely to get a concise "one size fits all" type of answer here. I would suggest looking into the links I've provided and do some research. You may find your answer in reading and looking around, or maybe able to modify your question a bit to scope it down.

Comment: With one size that fits the solutions its good. Better with two or three that'd give me more mental tools for future problems. Maybe some graphs from where I can derive some conditions in order to put them in an else if statement or something, and from there I can create the loops with what I know.

Comment: I feel I need a formal verification process to check if my idea is going to work in practice. And I think I need to do that before typing because I might loose a lot of time testing.

Comment: You may be interested in [formal verification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification), which again would be nontrivial to use in a coding competition. I think randomly testing a lot of input-output would be the best method (along with edge cases).

Comment: I'm aware testing is very important. I guess that is another stage in the process. I think that if someone writes good code with formal verification or some other tool, then the test are going to pass faster and he/she would be needing to make less editions on the code before passing all the tests.

Comment: This question sounds extremely broad.  One could write an entire book on it, and people have; see, e.g., [Competitive Programming 3 by Steven Halim and Felix Halim](https://cpbook.net/), [Cracking the Coding Interview by Gayle McDowell](http://www.crackingthecodinginterview.com/), [Competitive Programmers Handbook by Antti Laaksonen](https://cses.fi/book.pdf), https://ciiwiki.ecs.baylor.edu/index.php/Experiments_for_Data_Structures,_Algorithms_and_Strategies_Solving_Problems_based_on_Programming_Contests, and more.

Comment: Such questions are too broad to fit well here; we seek focused questions can be answered in a few paragraphs.